# Background colour being set somewhere invisible?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a very unique issue with a background colour.

I have built a website using WordPress and WooCommerce and all of a sudden, the background of the product pages has gone black.

I have trawled the code of every element in the chain and there is nowhere in the CSS that is setting this to black and I am completely perplexed at how this is happening.

See here: http://new.janomesewingcentre.com.au/shop/sewing-machines/janome-dc6050/

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: ```#footercontainer { background-color: #0b0b0b; }```

Comment: My guess is unclosed (or wrongly closed) `<div>`  tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<div>` tags in your markup which are causing your footer to merge with rest of the contents. See screenshot below.

[image: Invalid Markup]

Comment: Ok. So that's it. Perfect. I used this http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder to find the tag and delete it...